# Laravel custom validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-3

*--- Custom validation class (application/libraries/validator.php) ---*

```php
 class Validator extends Laravel\Validator {
    public function validate_passwdU($attribute, $value, $parameters){
        $r_uppercase    = '/[A-Z]/';  //Uppercase
        $default_min = 1;
        if(is_numeric($parameters[0])>=$default_min){
        $default_min = $parameters[0];
        }
        return (preg_match_all($r_uppercase,$value, $matches)>=$default_min);       
    }
}
```

*--- application/language/en/validation.php ---*

```php
    "passwdU" => "The :attribute must be at least :size uppercase characters."
```

*--- Controller ---*

```php
    $rules = array(
        'passwd' => 'required|min:8|passwdU:2'
    );

    $validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if ($validation->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::to('URL')->with_errors($validation);
    }
```

*--- Input ---*

passwd = 11111111

*--- View ---*

```php
<pre>
<?php print_r($errors); ?>
</pre>
```

*--- Output ---*

```php
Laravel\Messages Object
(
    [messages] => Array
    (
        [passwd] => Array
            (
                [0] => validation.passwdU
            )

    )
    [format] => :message
)
```

Why didn't I get the message that I defined in Language file?

Comment: As it's the message object sent back have you tried `print_r($errors->get('passwd'))`

Comment: @DavidBarker,  
Array
(
    [0] => validation.passwdU
)

Comment: I found the problem, in language I defined "passwdU" => "......", when the file is loaded, the key is converted to lowercase "passwdu" => "...".

Comment: makes sense, glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 0):

Passing messages method to the view

```php
return Redirect::to('login')
    ->withErrors($validator->messages())
```

and printing it with get method

```
{{ $errors->get('email') }}
```

worked for me:

```
The email field is required.
```

Comment: It's the same passing `->withErrors($validator)` , since `Validator` class *implements* `MessageProviderInterface` *interface*.